# What is the difference between "TextAlignment" and "HorizontalContentAlignment" in a XAML Textbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I see that a XAML Textbox control has `TextAlignment`, `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties.

From what I've tested `TextAlignment="Center"` is the same as `HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"` and `TextAlignment` doesn't have the "Top" and "Bottom" options the `VerticalContentAlignment` has. Setting `TextAlignment="Center"` leaves the text floating to the top of the Textbox, so I can see there is a difference between `TextAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`.

However what is the difference between `TextAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment`?

Comment: `TextAlignment` has a higher precedence than the `HorizontalContentAlignment`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, it just seems weird to have both if they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HorizontalContentAlignment` is a property that is inherited from the `Control` class.

`TextAlignment` is a more specific property. Like the `TextBlock`, the `TextBox` control allows setting the text justification using this property that it defines using the `AddOwner`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.addowner?view=netframework-4.8) method. The property is originally defined in the abstract `Block` class.

Comment: So it's just a consequence of inheriting both `Control` and `Block`?

Comment: It's a "consequence" of inheriting `Control`. The `TextAlignment` property is added for convenience basically.

Comment: Any idea why they would do that if `HorizontalContentAlignment` already exists?

Comment: @J.Doe: Well, no, I didn't implement it.